# Cloudfront Distribution: Deliver from custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to load all my static resources for my website using the `amazon cloudfront distribution`. I have configured everything and I am able to load my files using the `cloudfront domain URL`.
[image]

I have also added a `SSL certificate with ACM` for my site domains `*.mydomain.com` and verified and added the custom SSL configuration to the distribution.
I have also added the `Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)` : `test.mydomain.com` to the distribution.

What I am trying to do is load my static files using the url `https://test.mydomain.com/animate.css` which I am currently not able to. But I am getting the same file using the cloudfront URL `https://myclouddomain.cloudfront.net/animate.css`

I have also tried this after renaming my bucket to `test.mydomain.com` and is still not working.
Am I missing something here or is there any other configurations I need to do to load these files using my domain.

Comment: I think this document will be of some help http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-procedures.html#cnames-and-https-updating-cloudfront

Comment: @edwiser. I have tried according to the document but its still not working for me.

Comment: Did you actually change the DNS entry for your custom domain... to actually point to CloudFront?  Please review your question and for each time you make a statement like "it's not working," remove that statement and, instead, describe what is happening and compare that what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 0):

In your DNS registrar, make sure you have created a CNAME test.mydomain.com and pointed it to myclouddomain.cloudfront.net.

Elaborate on *"it is not working"*, what's the error code/message?

- DNS issue - point test.mydomain.com to myclouddomain.cloudfront.net in your domain registrar,
- 400 Bad Request - make sure the CNAME is properly configured in CloudFront
- 502 Bad Gateway - make sure the origin has an SSL certificate valid for: 
  CloudFront CNAME if you are **forwarding the Host Header**,
  CloudFront Origin domain name if you are **not forwarding the Host Header**